# Swapping C variable

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

As an exercise, I'm trying to swap variable content with a function that takes void pointers as parameters.
I cannot figure out why it return always a random value for the first variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(void* vp1, void* vp2, int size)
{ 
  char buffer[size];
  memcpy(buffer, vp1, size);
  memcpy(vp1, vp2, size);
  memcpy(vp2, buffer, size);
}

void main()
{
  int g1 = 243;
  int g2 = 28;

  printf("g1 before swap = %i\n", g1);
  printf("g2 before swap = %i\n", g2);

  printf("&g1 = %p\n", &g1);
  printf("&g2 = %p\n", &g2);

  swap(&g1, &g2, sizeof(int*));

  printf("-------------------------\n");

  printf("g1 after swap = %i\n", g1);
  printf("g2 after swap = %i\n", g2);

  printf("&g1 = %p\n", &g1);
  printf("&g2 = %p\n", &g2);
}
```

```
./swap
g1 before swap = 243
g2 before swap = 28
&g1 = 0x7ffee832072c
&g2 = 0x7ffee8320728
-------------------------
g1 after swap = -399374528
g2 after swap = 243
&g1 = 0x7ffee832072c
&g2 = 0x7ffee8320728
```

Example is directly taken from [this course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eR4rxnM7Lc&t=1801s), pretty interesting though

Comment: you probably want `sizeof(int)` rather than `sizeof(int *)`.

Comment: Thanks, that's it :)

Comment: Tipp: Instead of `sizeof(TYPE)` prefer to use `sizeof(EXPRESSION)`, e.g. in your case `sizeof(g1)`.

Comment: And if you want to practice defensive coding throw in an `assert(sizeof(g1) == sizeof(g2))` ...

Comment: It's `sizeof EXPRESSION`, as `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are swapping with the wrong size, on your system `sizeof (int*)` is bigger than `sizeof (int)`.

As we can see from your output, `sizeof (int*)` is 8, but `sizeof (int)` is 4. When copying from `g1` to `buffer` 4 more bytes are fetched which will overwrite the contents of `g1` when copying `buffer` to `g2`.

Change the call into

```
swap(&g1, &g2, sizeof g1);
```

If you like to know the size of an object like `g1`, use `sizeof g1`.

Comment: I understand but it's confusing because it works with `sizeof(int*)` on one computer (Ubuntu) , not on another (MacOS)... do you know why and if it's related to the OS (I suppose) ?

Comment: No, it's related to the compiler system which defines the sizes of `int` and pointers. You have to read the documentation or write a simple test program to see the sizes. On some systems like 32-bit Ubuntu pointers and `int` might have the same size, but there is no general rule. On microcontrollers like 8051 pointers use 1 to 3 bytes, depending on the kind of pointer, and `int` use 2 bytes. Just use the object, or if it's not possible the correct type.

Comment: Which flavour of Ubuntu did you try? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, on this system, printing `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(int*)` return 4 and 8

Comment: Then it was mere chance that it worked on Ubuntu. Did you check the addresses of `g1` and `g2`? Is the address of `g2` higher than the address of `g1`? Look at your code, the order matters.

Comment: Oh, it appears that on the linux one the first memory allocated addr is always lower than the second one (4 bytes difference), in the macos that's is the opposite, that could explain because when I copy from `g1` to `g2` on the macos I copy at the also the first 4 bytes from`g2` ?
On ubuntu, by chance the consecutive bytes copied from `g2` are null which doesn't break the test